# Printing High Resolution Open Maps?

Tags: qgis, printing, print-composer, resolution

I hope my question does not silly but I am QGIS rookie and am really struggling to find a solution.

I have the added the Google Street Layer to my project on top of which I worked with my points  and polylines.

I am using the composer to print the final map in a pdf format. My shape files get printed very well however the google openmap layer has very large pixels. And this is only for an A4 size. Imagine how it will look for larger sizes such as A1 or A0.

This is a link to the pdf file in my Dropbox should you like to check how it looks: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102908644/QGIS/Test.pdf

Is there a solution to fixing the resolution issue when printing the maps?

Comment: Google tiles are only 256px by 256px - you would need to get high resolution tiles - the Google static maps does this 640x640 (returns 1280x1280 pixels) for free - Enterprise [Business] will get you 1024x1024 (returns 2048x2048 pixels) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Imagesizes

Comment: It does not really matter for me whether it is a google, yahoo, bing or any other map, as long as I can print it in a large format at a good quality. I will keep updating this one and it will cover the entire London.

Comment: I heard it could work if I get a high resolution map and geo-reference it.I am only looking for a solution to get this done. I noticed the maps in my office which have very high resolution and I wonder how do they do it.

Comment: No sure you are understanding most online web tile servers are 256px by 256px for WEB Mapping (not large scale printing). If You need high res you will require vector data - http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles

Answer (score 2):

You can make screen copies of the Openlayers background (without your vector data) in higher zoom levels with `File -> Save picture as...`

In a next step, you can stitch several screenshots together to get a raster file with the same zoom level you used, but greater than one screen.

If you use that as background instead of the Openlayers tiles, you get a higher resolution background for printing.

Only thing I do not know if this is according to the license policy of Google and bing.

Comment: Can be for personal use only - I am not a lawyer.